# Putting <textarea><textarea></textarea></textarea> causes </textarea> not to show up

Tags: html

I'm not entirely sure why this is, but when I put `<textarea><textarea></textarea></textarea>`, the textarea only shows the text `"<textarea>"`, which is not what I expect.

```html
<textarea><textarea></textarea></textarea>
```

What I'm after is for the textarea box to have the text `"<textarea></textarea>"`. Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 1):

The end tag for a textarea element will end the element.

If you want to display characters with special meaning in HTML, use entities. `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&amp;` etc.